# How to hide options table,request,response from kibana-4 visualizer?

Tags: kibana-4

I have created a dashboard in Kibana-4 and shared on my Web-app. 
There is option to see table,request,response how to hide it?

Answer (score 0):

To remove option Request/Response of visualizer
I have made changes in kibana file "src/public/index.js".
Removed require('registry/spy_modes') for request/Response

```
.register(function () {
return {
  name: 'request',
  display: 'Request',
  order: 2,
  template: reqRespStatsHTML,
  link: linkReqRespStats
};
})
.register(function () {
return {
  name: 'response',
  display: 'Response',
  order: 3,
  template: reqRespStatsHTML,
  link: linkReqRespStats
};
})
```